# React Modal in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I have used react-modal for modal dialog,

and in my reactjs render(), i have the following modal

```
return(
        <ReactModal
        isOpen={this.state.showModal}
        contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example">
        <button style={styleClose} onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>
      CloseModal</button>
        {items}
     </ReactModal>
    )
```

But when this dialog open, the items behind are overlapping, how can I have only dialog being visible and not the background elements?

The elements that are overlapping are the components that have radiobuttons. Normal text are not overlapping. How can i make these buttons not to overlap?

I tried setting the zIndex and apply styling but that doesnt work.

Also how can i have close when i also click esc on keyboard ?

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping? can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I mean when the dialog open, the radio buttons on main screen are visble on modal dialog, and i can still access and change the radio buttons tht is on the main page and not the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question needs more info for clarification, I can answer the second part:

Add this to your modal element:
`shouldCloseOnEsc={true}`

If you haven't, remember to also add `onRequestClose={<your component method that hides the modal}`

Check this link for more usage: http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/#usage

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried the shouldCloseOnEsc={true} inside ReactModal tag, as shown below:                                                                                    
    <ReactModal
         isOpen={this.state.showModal}
         shouldCloseOnEsc={true}
         shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}>    </ReactModal>                                                                                               but doesnt work!

Comment: @pgman I think you are missing the `onRequestClose={this.closeModal}` also in your props. For `closeModal` method you can call it to hide modal.

Comment: Thanks that works for closing the dialog! It would be really helpful if you could throw some light on setting he zIndex.

Comment: Did you try directly setting the `className` prop?

Comment: `className="ReactModal__Content"` then go into css and add some z-index to this class